# Assigning Managed Package Licenses in a Sandbox

Tags: managed-package, licenses, sandbox

In our production organization, we can access the following page either through a related list on the User object (Manage Licenses) or through a link in Installed Packages next to the package.

[image]

We have a full copy sandbox and want to give a new user (a user we create in the sandbox) a license for an installed package (our managed package) as we do not want them logging in as an admin.

However, neither the related list nor the link are present in the sandbox.  Do licenses need to be assigned in Production and then refresh the sandbox?

Comment: So does the ability to Manage Licenses for other installed packages in the Sandbox go away. We installed an app in our Production org and then refreshed our Sandbox. The ability to Manage Licenses in the Sandbox is gone.

Comment: Does this only apply to the Full Sandbox and not Production?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a sandbox is created from an org with an active managed package license the sandbox will act as if it had a site license. The net effect of this is that all users in the org are automatically and always licensed without having to manage licensing per-user.

I don't know if this behavior is documented but I've seen it time and time again while working for ISVs.

Answer (score 0):

CA_Peterson is correct.  A site license is assigned so all users have access to the package by default.

If you need to be able to assign licenses contact your solution provider with the sandbox organization id and they can set the number of licenses for the sandbox.

Note* When licenses are assigned by default access is revoked from all users and licenses must be provisioned as the license assignment is not copied to the sandbox.