# Sandbox refresh and manage packages

Tags: managed-package, sandbox-refresh

When we refresh sandbox all the metadata and some data is refreshed and it makes replica /subset of production.

I have one managed package installed on my production (its not app exchange app  but just manage package)

My question is: If i refresh the sandbox will i get the replica of manage package as well?

I think it should but not 100% sure. Any authentic source of information will help me to proceed with confidence.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refreshed sandbox will have all installed package from the production and all packages which you have created in production.

This may help you [Assigning Managed Package Licenses in a Sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/assigning-managed-package-licenses-in-a-sandbox) to prove that packages automatically copy to sandbox.