# Installed Packages in Sandbox not working after refresh from Prod

Tags: managed-package, package-install, skuid

After a long time, we did a refresh from production into our Development Sandbox. And now, I somehow can't get to see the "Manage Licenses" link. Neither am I am able to Assign Users to the managed package. The only link shown is for uninstall.  I checked my profile, and I have the "Manage Packages" permission.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to this question: [Assigning Managed Package Licenses in a Sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/assigning-managed-package-licenses-in-a-sandbox?rq=1)

By default, when you refresh a Sandbox of a Production org that has a Managed Package installed with per-user license management, the Sandbox will have a "Site" license to that Managed Package, so you will not be able to assign individual users to that Managed Package -- all users in the Sandbox will have access to that Managed Package.

This can be problematic, though, if you're trying to have different behaviors for users without licenses to the given Managed Package, or trying to prevent the Managed Package's functionality from running unless a user is licensed to that Managed Package.

In this case, if you're not going to be refreshing this Sandbox very often, you can ask the ISV who created the Managed Package and ask them to go into the License Management Application (LMA), find your Sandbox License record, and switch the licensing from the default (Site License) to a per-user licensing model --- this will allow you to assign some users licenses to the Managed Package in your Sandbox while having other users not be licensed. I've done this before at my company so I know this is possible and we've done it before on occasion.

Comment: Thanks Zac. Yes, my managed package has a per-user license, as well as different user license type like admin and viewer only.     Wow.. So that means each time I do a refresh, I would need to contact the ISV to make it proper on the Sandbox?  That's bad.  :(      Do you know if every ISV would have such License Management app?

Comment: I'm not sure that it will have to be "re-done" every time, as the License record is persistent. And yes, every ISV has the same License Management App, it's a part of the standard toolset Salesforce provides to each ISV. Also there are not different License types, all License types in Salesforce are the same. You may be charged different amounts by the ISV but license types are all the same. I know for the app Skuid that they don't sell you different license types for Admin / Viewer - you manage that distinction with Permission Sets.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, so I wanted to provide solution for other users that may experience this same issue today, the solution is to go to setup>company information>match production license.